# Are Layout Directives supported by Angular 2 Material Design Components?

Tags: angular, flexbox, material-design

I'm trying to use the [Angular2 Material Design](https://github.com/angular/material2) components, and I can't get any of the [layout directives](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container) to work. Example:

According to the examples, this should "just work":

```
<div layout="row">
  <div flex>First item in row</div>
  <div flex>Second item in row</div>
</div>
<div layout="column">
  <div flex>First item in column</div>
  <div flex>Second item in column</div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't - it just renders the elements on the page as plain old divs. (I'm using the latest version of Chrome).

Am I missing something, like is there a CSS file I'm supposed to import?

Comment: The very first lines of their doc has instructions on how to import it if you are using SystemJS. Do you see with Developer Tools the requests for the CSS?

Comment: I've got the components working (such as Button - I did update my SystemJs config file for that), but layout doesn't work.
I do not see any request for any kind of material design css.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

**January 2017 Update**:

Angular 2 team recently added a new NPM package [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) for layout only. It is a separate package independent of angular material.
The full instructions are available in the [github page](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) README.

Install the module:

> npm install @angular/flex-layout -save

In app.module.ts (or equivalent), declare the module:

```ts
import {FlexLayoutModule} from "@angular/flex-layout";

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
     ...
     FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Markup example:

```ts
<div class="flex-container" 
     fxLayout="row" 
     fxLayout.xs="column"
     fxLayoutAlign="center center"
     fxLayoutAlign.xs="start">
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex="20%" fxFlex.xs="40%">  </div>
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex>        </div>
  <div class="flex-item" fxFlex="25px"> </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [plunker sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/h8hzyoEyqdCXmTBA7DfK?p=preview) taken from the flex-layout github page.

---

**Original Answer**:

The [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container) you are referring to are for angular1 material. Angular2 material still doesn't have any layout directives.

You can easily create the directive yourself in a simple way.

All you need to know:

`layout="row"`  is same as `style="display:flex;flex-direction:row"`
`layout="column"` => `style="display:flex;flex-direction:column"`

And `flex` is equal to `style="flex:1"`

As directives:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector:'[layout]'
})
export class LayoutDirective{
  @Input() layout:string;
  @HostBinding('style.display') display = 'flex';

  @HostBinding('style.flex-direction')
  get direction(){
       return (this.layout === 'column') ? 'column':'row';
  }
}
```

The flex directive, use it like: `<div flex>` or `<div flex="10">` any number from 0 - 100%. Also, just for fun, I added shrink and grow inputs

```ts
@Directive({
  selector:'[flex]'
})
export class FlexDirective{
    @Input() shrink:number = 1;
    @Input() grow:number = 1;
    @Input() flex:string;

    @HostBinding('style.flex')
    get style(){
        return `${this.grow} ${this.shrink} ${this.flex === '' ? '0':this.flex}%`;
    }
}
```

To use them everywhere without adding them to each component:

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,FlexDirective ,LayoutDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is a sample in [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mDLq4i5mai0kxioIlIEK?p=preview)

Comment: As someone who's new to the material library, this had me scratching my head for a while... It's difficult to tell which directives are NG2 only.

Comment: `forRoot` does not exist on that module anymore... https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Integration-with-Angular-CLI

Answer (score 3):

No need to write a new directive until Material2 provide us the LayoutModule.

You just have to import the angular layouts-attributes.css from angular1.
It takes the old directive as css selector.

> require('node_modules/angular-material/modules/layouts/angular-material.layouts-attributes.css')

for example the css for directive layout-align="end" it use the css
selector: [layout-align="end"]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [angular2-polymer](https://github.com/vaadin/angular2-polymer) in order to pull in Polymer's [iron-flex-layout](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-flex-layout?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-flex-layout). It is slightly more limited and has a slightly different API than the Material 1 layout (but the Material 2 layout will also have a different API). But it works now and is supported.

There is also a guide [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout).